# Ubuntu 14.04 - upowerd crashed with SIGSEGV in service_client_free()

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu

I'm experiencing crashes in Ubuntu 14.04 (XFCE/Xubuntu Desktop Environment installed to replace the Unity Desktop Environment) with the following message:

```
Sorry, Ubuntu 14.04 has experienced an internal error.
ExecutablePath: /usr/lib/upower/upowerd
Package       : upower 0.9.23-2ubuntu1
ProblemType   : Crash
Title         : upowerd crashed with SIGSEGV in service_client_free()
...
UnreportableReason: You have some obsolete packages installed. Please...
    apt-utils, libapt-inst1.5, libapt-pkg4.12
```

Apparently, the report claims that some obsolete packages could be responsible.  Is this the problem (note that I have always been keeping my system up to date)?

Any way to fix this?

Comment: The same happening to me everyday.

Comment: Not sure as to the problem but a user confirmed the problem occurs when they connect their iPad via USB, and it just happened to me connecting my iPhone via USB. Looks like a bug that occurs with iOS devices. I am not noticing any problems since the error so I guess it's just a silent one

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug that seems to affect ubuntu users using iOS devices: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upower/+bug/604809

One solution I've come across:

```
sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-utils
```

and reboot (from: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2256436). But it doesn't seem to have stopped the error from coming up after a suspend.